# Nativescript Cannot find module 'nativescript-angular/http'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nativescript

I am following the NativeScript tutorial here:

[Native Script Angular - Chapter 3](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3)

I'm having an error when trying to import `nativescript-angular/http`. it says *Cannot find module 'nativescript-angular/http'*. Am I missing anything? I noticed that there is not `http.js` under node_modules/native-script-angular/http.js.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to install npm packages?

Comment: Hello scokmen, not sure what you mean by that, but I followed the tutorial and installed NativeScript through NPM. So I guess the npm packages are installed, right?

Comment: In the root of your project run `npm i`?

Comment: Also, do you have a references file?

Comment: I tried this @GeorgeEdwards but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, i ran the npm i on a different directory. I have tried this (on the right directory), and it kind of refreshed the node_modules path. But it still gives me the error. Based on the tutorial, http module should be found under nativescript-angular folder. Is this an oversight on the tutorial? should I copy the http modules from node_modules folder to the nativescript-angular folder?

Comment: What version of `nativescript-angular` do you have installed? Do you get this error when you run `tsc` or `tns build` ? Sometimes the intellisense just gets a bit confused. I'd also try deleting and reinstalling the node_modules just to be sure nothing is corrupted. Also, what OS are you working on?

Comment: I often find these "Can't find module X" errors within nativescript are fixed via deleting `platforms`, `hooks` and `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty sure that the version of Angular you are using are no longer support `'http'` service, try to use `'http-client'` instead.

```
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";
```

Or use Angular version 5 or older.

Answer (score 3):

You include in file app.module.ts next  "NativeScriptHttpModule"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to look for NativeScriptHttpClientModule was not quite enough to fix this for me.  I additionally had to remove the '/http' from the end.  It's able to find the module in the 'nativescript-angular' directory without the reference to the sub directory.

```
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular"
```

Comment: Look into node_modules. With version 8, the name of package is changed so Change 
`import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";`

to
`import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "@nativescript/angular";`


I was migrating from V7 to V8 NativeScript

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. All I had to do was to remove `package-lock.json` file along with my `node_modules` folder and `npm install` after that.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your angular and nativescript to the current version; I can help you do that if you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
```

In app.module

```
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";
imports: [NativeScriptHttpClientModule]
```

Answer (score -1):

From within your groceries folder you just need to run the following commands to update the version.

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ npm-check-updates -u
$ npm install
```

When package.json updated to the following it worked for me

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
"tns-core-modules": "2.2.1",
"nativescript-angular": "0.3.1"
},
```

If you compare the version you will see that NS _HTTP_PROVIDERS is within the current master but not version 2.0.0 that is included with the sample

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/http/ns-http.ts